# jq_link_to_remote submit form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony1, symfony-1.4

How can I submit a form via POST with jq_link_to_remote and update the div?

testSuccess.php

```
 <div id="list">
 <form name="list" action="<?= url_for('shoppinglist/update'); ?>" method="post">
 .
 //some input text.
 .
 <?php
 function addlink() {

$linkname = "+";
 return jq_link_to_remote($linkname, array(
    'update' => 'list',
    'url' => 'shoppinglist/update',
    'data' => 'list', //this might be the problem.
    'loading' => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
    'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
    'method' => 'post',
 ));

}
echo addlink();
?>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Cart" onClick="submitForm()">
</form>
</div>
```

### Update

When I use this:

```
<?php
echo form_remote_tag( array(
'url'      => '@shoppinglist/update', // even when I don't type "@“
'update'   => 'list',
'loading'  => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
 ));
 ?>
```

Error: Call to undefined function form_remote_tag()

When I use this:

```
function addlink() {

$linkname = "+";
 return jq_form_remote_tag($linkname, array(
     'url' => '@shoppinglist/update', // even when I don't type "@“
    'update' => 'list',
    'loading' => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
    'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
    'method' => 'post',
 ));

}
//I just echo a link!
echo  addlink();
```

Error: Notice: Undefined index: url in ... JQueryHelper.php line 353 and 410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [`jq_form_remote_tag`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfJqueryReloadedPlugin/1.2/trunk/lib/helper/jQueryHelper.php#L394) instead?

```
<?php echo jq_form_remote_tag(array(
  'url'      => 'shoppinglist/update',
  'update'   => 'list',
  'loading'  => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
  'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
)) ?>
```

I don't get the difference between `addlink` and `submitForm` ?

**edit:**

Well, you should set your template like that

```
<div id="list">
  <?php echo jq_form_remote_tag(array(
  'url'      => 'shoppinglist/update',
  'update'   => 'list',
  'loading'  => jq_visual_effect('fadeIn', '#indicator'),
  'complete' => jq_visual_effect('fadeOut', '#indicator'),
  )) ?>

    //some input text.

    <input type="submit" value="Cart" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. submitForm() was an C&P error. When I do your solution I get the error: undefined index url jQuery Helper.php on line 353. Why?

Comment: I don't know, what's on the line 353? What do you c/p of my code? Could you update your question with these informations (and also fix your bad c/p about `submitForm`?

Comment: How does symfony or php know that the button takes the action from jq_form_remote_tag? I don't see any relation to that? I mean from echo jq_form_remote_tag I don't see any button. Instead of my original post jq_link_to_remote. Just want to know and understand it.

Comment: `jq_form_remote_tag` won't display any button. It will act on the submit event to send the form using ajax when you will hit the submit button. That's why you can have a basic submit button and it will send the data using ajax.

Comment: Okay, I got it. But why doesn't jq_form_remote_tag go to 'url' => 'shoppinglist/update'. It goes to the original action which I am going to call the whole site, e.g. 'shoppinglist/index'.

Comment: With `jq_form_remote_tag` you are going nowhere. It will send the form data to the `url` parameter and then update the element `update` (here list) with the result.

Comment: But it goes straight forward to the action 'shoppinglist/index' as POST. Manually I tested the action 'shoppinglist/update'. It is working fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14681/discussion-between-j0k-and-craphunter)